# Making question

Tags: meaning, questions, negation, register

I'd like to know the difference between

1. Why **don't you** do it?
2. Why **do you not** do it?"

Could you please let me know the differences?

Comment: I recommend you to post it on ELL.

Comment: Would you tell us where you saw the second sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> Both are correct. What was originally just a contraction of "do not" has become a word in itself, and can now be placed where the two separate words can't.
>
> Both "Don't you..." and "Do you not..." are correct, but you can't re-expand "Don't you..." into "Do not you...".
>
> The meaning of the two are the same, but "Do you not..." is considered more formal in some situations.

This is quoted from [ELL](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8372/do-you-not-vs-dont-you) as an accepted answer.